# Azimuth, elevation and distance for point-to-point radio links

Tags: qgis, spherical-geometry

After plotting our point-to-point radio sites and links in QGIS using Ordnance Survey map layers I'm wondering whether I can extract some information for this.

For each link I would like to determine the azimuth and elevation of the antennas at either side such that the narrow beam from them will target the opposite site's antenna.

Furthermore, it would be useful to understand the distance of each link. I believe using the length attribute in QGIS gives me the length of a great circle rather than the distance the wave will travel.

Comment: so something like the length of the yellow line in [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/235183/55203), this [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk6YA.gif) ?

Comment: @StevenKay yes, straight line between antennas